# hibernate generates wrong sql "select max(id) from my_table"

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, code-generation

i did little app with Hibernate. just from samples available from the HB site.

Hibernate says to DB:

```
drop table if exists some_db.my_table 

create table some_db.my_table ......

select max(id) from my_table
```

when i turn from HSQL db to MySQL.

i am having error 
"DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'my_table' at line 1 [n/a]"

because HB stubbornly tries to say

```
select max(id) from my_table
```

instead of

```
select max(id) from some_db.my_table
```

which is correct syntax when it comes to

```
public void testBasicUsage() {
    // create a couple of events...
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save( new Event( ..... ) );   // <<-------------------HERE
    session.save(new Event( ..... ));
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

and changing dialect doesn't help.

i've tried to switch to different hb versions, for example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

but it doesn't help, too.

changing connection (standard "root"/"" access) like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/some_db
```

instead of

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
```

doesn't help either.

it seems to be a bug, but what would be a solution?

Comment: Entity was declared like this:

@Entity
@Table( name = "Event", schema = "some_db")

Comment: Entity was declared like this:

@Entity
@Table( name = "my_table", schema = "some_db")

Answer (score 2):

You really need to post your annotated entities / hibernate XML mapping for this.

The most likely cause is that you've not specified the schema property in the [table annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Table.html).

I.e. something along the lines of

```
@Table(schema="some_db")
```

Comment: yes, i did. as i said in my post - drop table if exists some_db.my_table 

create table some_db.my_table ......

select max(id) from my_table  and only last one always comes without schema/database name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use schema parameter:

```
<generator class="increment">
    <param name="schema">some_db</param>
</generator>
```